# .htaccess 301 redirect wildcard magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I am working on migrating a Magento site which is currently a multi store setup. I will be changing it from 4 different domains into 1 domain:

```
company.pl
company.de
company.us
company.com
```

all to:

```
company.com/uk 
company.com/de 
company.com/us 
company.com/pl
```

This is not an issue, magento is all capable of this quite simply, however, when I start the project this weekend we will be doing US and UK, this means that the shop in magento will become **company.com/uk/shop** instead of **company.com/shop**

I need to know how I can possibly use a 301 redirect maybe like a wildcard to do the following:

If the user visits: **company.com/shop/product.html** redirect to **company.com/uk/shop/product.html** using some kind of wildcard so I do not need to set up a 301 for every product in the website.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

> If the user visits: company.com/shop/product.html redirect to company.com/uk/shop/product.html

You can use this rule as **your first rule** in magento root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shop(/|$) /uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: shop is not a directory, it is a URI. would you recommend creating the directory, im not sure how this will work? I can try.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the last section in the square brackets? R=301 is defining it is a 301 redirect, NC and L?

Comment: `NC - No Case (ignore case) L - (Last rule)`

Comment: For some reason this has now worked. We have the old website which was website.de now magento is setting store codes to website.de/de which is fine for now, How can I blanked redirect when 4 domain names point to the server. I can not reply on just ^shop(/|$) because they may be hitting the website from .com also.

Comment: You mean you want to redirect `company.de/shop` OR `company.us/shop` to `company.uk/shop` ?

Comment: No, Im sorry things got really complicated yesterday with some other issues with urls. Turns out that Magento managed to some  how redirect all of its current URL's for the .de website, out .com we went down the route of running a export from Google Analytics to pull the top pages returning 404's and set up manual 301 redirects. Messy but works until google sorts itself out.